# Renamed variables and methods return back by themselves

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

When I am doing the mass renaming in IntelliJ, it does everything, but after changing appropriate getters or other methods, when I press the "done", all returns back to the previous state.

It is a known problem, but even on the [Jbrains Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206203469-Refactor-rename-stops-working?page=1#community_comment_115000094224) there is no answer.

Comment: you mean it changes getters/setters for you, but after sometime it reverts back??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I explain as I see it and as other people who had the same problem see it. It is not really so, it only LOOKS so. I have already found my misunderstanding, the answer is already below. As that problem/solution is not here on SO, I added it here.

Answer (score 0):

When you have at least somewhat complex rename, after you are pressing done, IntelliJ changes all to the previous state and shows the changes in the Refactoring Preview window - look for it below, similar to the Find tab. Sure This window has below the Do Refactor button. Simply press it. And close old one tabs of the same sort - probably you have many of them!